# Why is this question being closed?

Tags: discussion

[How many times a week is masturbating good for health?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5503/how-many-times-a-week-is-masturbating-good-for-health/5512#5512)

I see this question is being marked for closure due to answers being "opinion based".

So, what exactly is all the mountain of data on sexual health, the Kinsey Reports, the advice given in sexual health clinics etc?

Comment: Just for the record, a question being closed for one reason doesn't mean every one of those close votes was for that reason. I am pretty sure I didn't pick POB. (possibly "unclear" - it was badly worded before the edit and an "is X healthy?" question)

Comment: This is the sort of question that might be asked in a sexual health clinic. It's bizarre to me that it's being closed for what ever reason. As a clinician I'll attempt to answer any question I'm trained to answer.

Comment: and why all these downvotes, on both the question and the meta question.

Comment: @YviDe I wasn't aware that "is X healthy" type questions were off topic though I see it was discussed in biology.  It seems a lot of questions come from non-native English writers.  Is poorly worded English a reason for closure too because it reduces the quality of the content?

Comment: @Graham What does "is X healthy" mean? Is it asking whether something is dangerous? Whether something has health benefits? Whether something should be done less or more? In your answer to that question, for example, you only addressed the "is it dangerous?" interpretation, even though the question also asks how many times it is *good*, which might be interested as asking whether it has health *benefits*.  I think those questions are unclear without more detail added.

Comment: When there is no known health benefit, I think it's appropriate to answer the complementary question.  That's how we do it in medicine.  But one could also answer that the activity in question is well within the normals as established by Kinsey etc.